# Отображение кода в приложении

Tags: java, android, xml

Мне нужно отобразить определённые блоки (отрывки) кода в **Android** приложении.

Как, например, тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е существует ли некая ***"CodeView"***, которая может отображать исходники на экране активности с подчёркиванием синтаксиса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен MarkDown Viewer, то есть просмотровщик разметки используемой и в SO:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем спокойно можно показывать код.

Погуглите исходники просмотровщиков `.md` файлов или [поищите на github](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=markdown+viewer&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: А его подключить к AndroidStudio трудно будет?

Comment: Для прогера среднего уровня агрессивности - 5-минутная задача, с пониженной агрессивностью на пару часиков видимо :)